# VueJS extend component: remove parent's property

Tags: javascript, merge, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two Vue components, one extends the other:

```js
// CompA.vue

export default {
    props: {
        value1: Object,
    },

    data: function () {
        return {
            value2: 'hello2 from A',
            value3: 'hello3 from A'
        }
    }
}

// CompB.vue

import CompA from './CompA.vue';

export default {
    extends: CompA,

    props: {
        value4: Object
    },

    data: function(){
        return {
            value2: 'hello2 from B'
        }
    }
}
```

As described [in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends), CompB's options are merged into CompA's, resulting:

```js
{
    props: {
        value1: Object,
        value4: Object
    },

    data: function () {
        return {
            value2: 'hello2 from B',
            value3: 'hello3 from A'
        }
    }
}
```

However my desired result is having property `value1` removed:

```js
{
    props: {
        value4: Object
    },

    data: function () {
        return {
            value2: 'hello2 from B',
            value3: 'hello3 from A'
        }
    }
}
```

I think it should be possible using [Custom Option Merge Strategies](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Custom-Option-Merge-Strategies)

But even if I return `null` or `undefined`, the property isn't removed.

```js
Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.data = function(parentVal, childVal) {
    return null;
};
```

Is it even possible to such thing? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you just want to remove all properties from the object that is being extended?

Comment: No, only specific ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me how `Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies` works but this does work in a test environment.

```
import CompA from './CompA.vue';
// make a deep clone copy of CompA. Here I'm just using a made up copy
// function but you could use lodash or some other library. Do NOT use
// JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) because you will lose functions. Also
// Object.assign will not work because Object.assign performs a shallow
// copy (meaning if you delete from props, which is a nested object, you
// will still globally delete the property).
import copy from "./utils" 
//copy CompA
let newCompA = copy(CompA)    
// delete the desired props
delete newCompA.props.value1

export default {
    // extend the copy
    extends: newCompA,

    props: {
        value4: Object
    },

    data: function(){
        return {
            value2: 'hello2 from B'
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, delete the props you do not want before you extend the component.

Comment: Meanwhile I figured it out, my way is very similar to yours. However I'll accepts yours, because it works too and you deserve it.

Comment: Although I have to note that that delete removes that property 'globally' causing side-effects, ie. when using CompA without extending it, the property is removed  anyway (because the delete statements runs anyway because of complied together). But this was beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @balping I was just looking into that. I think your solution might be better. I'm trying with a copy of CompA, but it's not working as expected. If I get it to work I'll post the solution.

Comment: @balping Alright got it working. I was getting tripped up with Object.assign doing a shallow clone.

Answer (score 9):

This is my own solution that finally worked for me: delete the property manually in `beforeCreate()`.

This is very similar to Bert's answer.

```
// CompB.vue

import CompA from './CompA.vue';

export default {
    extends: CompA,

    props: {
        value4: Object
    },

    data: function(){
        return {
            value2: 'hello2 from B'
        }
    },

    beforeCreate: function(){
        Vue.delete(this.$options.props, 'value1');
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you need it. 
But you could also do it like following:

- With `Object.assign`:

  ```
  extends: Object.assign({}, compA, {
      props: {
          value4: Object
      }
  }),
  ```
- With [spread-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...compA`:

  ```
  extends: { 
      ...compA,
      props: {
          value4: Object
      }
  }
  ```

Please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/rmdr8p2f/).

```js
const compA = {
  name: 'CompA',
  template: `
   <div>
    <h2>{{$options.name}}</h2>
    props: <br/> 
    <span v-if="$options.name === 'CompA'">1 - {{value1}}<br/></span>
    <span v-if="$options.name === 'CompB'">4 - {{value4}}<br/></span>
    {{value2}}<br/>
    {{value3}}
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    value1: Object,
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      value2: 'hello2 from A',
      value3: 'hello3 from A'
    }
  }
}

const compB = {
  name: 'CompB',
  extends: Object.assign({}, compA, {
    props: {
      value4: Object
    }
  }),

  /*
  // with spread operator
  { 
   ...compA,
   props: {
     value4: Object
    }
  },*/
  data: function() {
    return {
      value2: 'hello2 from B'
    }
  }
}

console.log('no prop value1', compB)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    compA,
    compB
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp-a :value1="{id: 2}">
  </comp-a>
  <comp-b :value1="{id: 4}" :value4="{id: 9}">
  </comp-b>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I need it, because I want to use have a property in CompB as mutable data, instead of immutable prop, but while keeping the name. If it's not removed from props, you can define it inside data(), it remains a prop anyway. Maybe it's not best practice but as long it works in a reliable way, I don't really care.